# Only set the value once when two table view cells have the mostly the same components

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, swift

I have two prototype cells. Most of the UI are the same except one has a image view and the other one don't. The situation is that in cellForRowAtIndexPath, when I set the value for these cell's labels. I have to set them each time in two cells. Can I just set them once and only set the image for the cell only has a image view?

For example:

`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let place = places[indexPath.row] as Place
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ImageCell
            cell.nameLabel = names[indexPath.row]
            cell.screeNameLabel = screenNames[indexPath.row]
            cell.createAtLable = place.createdAt.shortTimeAgoSinceNow()
            cell.profileImageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(imageURL)
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BaseCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as BaseCell
            cell.nameLabel = names[indexPath.row]
            cell.screeNameLabel = screenNames[indexPath.row]
            cell.createAtLable = place.createdAt.shortTimeAgoSinceNow()
            return cell
        }
    }`

As you can see, both cells have the same nameLabel, screeNameLabel, createAtLable. How do I only have to set them once? The above code is only a example. My current project, I have a lot of ui in the cells and they are basically the same except one has a image and one don't.

And by the way, what's the best way for this situation. When a cell contains most the same components, only a few components are different. Are using multiple prototype cells the best way?

Comment: subclass cell add a bool flag and check for it

Comment: @amar I kow how to check it. No need to add a book flag. A isKindOfClass would do. The real problem is how to set the value for different cell only once.

Comment: You can solve it by auto layout. You can use the same cell prototype. What you need to do is set the height of image view to "greater than or equal to 0" if you want to let it expand according to different image. Since imageView has intrinsic content height and width it will expand or shrink according to what  you load.

Comment: Okay let me know if it worked. I have tried on my own and it seems to work. Only you need to set the all the other constraint carefully. The key is making height of imageview 0 when there is no content.

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha it worked. I change the height constraint to less than 150. And it worked out of box. Thanks!

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha one more question if I changed a constraint constant, should I call setNeedsUpdateConstraints immediately? If not which one should I call to make it affect?

Comment: So you are adding constraints programatically? If  you are changing constraints on some event you need to call setNeedsUpdateConstraints for any view that you are updating constraints in future once (in your case may be in your custom cell class). System will call updateConstraints as you change the constraint.

Comment: No. I add the constraint in storyboard, and then change the constraint constant programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by auto layout. You can use the same cell prototype. What you need to do is set the height of image view to "greater than or equal to 0" if you want to let it expand according to different image height or "less than or equal to some constant if you want the image view height to be fixed. Since imageView has intrinsic content height and width it will expand or shrink according to what you load. The key is to make image view height 0 when there is no content.